# Java threads not starting / working as expected

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, networking

I am implementing a simple client-server architecture where multiple clients should be able to connect to the server and strings could be exchanged between the server and client.

My idea is that I'll have two threads on each side: a listener, constantly checking if there is anything new in the inputstream, and a writer thread, that writes into the socket if there is something to write.

However, the second thread doesn't even start... Only the first sysout is displayed.

```
    //start new thread to handle client input
    new Thread(
            new ServerWorker(clientSocket, this, this.getIdCounter())).start();
    System.out.println("server side listener started");

    //start new thread to handle client output
    new Thread(new ServerWorkerListener(clientSocket)).start();
    System.out.println("server side writer started");
```

Here is some code from the ServerWorker:

```
public void run() {
    try {
        OutputStream output = clientSocket.getOutputStream();
        while (true) {
            // output.write(("Pling!\n\n").getBytes());

            for (Client tempClient : server.getClientList()) {
                if ((tempClient.getId() == this.id)
                        && tempClient.isShouldSend()) {

                    output.write((tempClient.getOutputStream() + "\n\n")
                            .getBytes());
                    tempClient.setInputStream("");
                    tempClient.setShouldSend(false);
                }
            }

        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error in serverWorker");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

I really don't know what I'm missing...

Whole of ServerWorker:
        public class ServerWorker implements Runnable {

```
protected Socket clientSocket = null;
protected String serverText = null;
protected int id;
protected Server server;

public ServerWorker(Socket clientSocket, Server server,
        int id) {
    this.clientSocket = clientSocket;
    this.serverText = serverText;
    this.id = id;
    this.server = server;
}

public void run() {
    try {
        OutputStream output = clientSocket.getOutputStream();
        while (true) {
            // output.write(("Pling!\n\n").getBytes());

            for (Client tempClient : server.getClientList()) {
                if ((tempClient.getId() == this.id)
                        && tempClient.isShouldSend()) {

                    output.write((tempClient.getOutputStream() + "\n\n")
                            .getBytes());
                    tempClient.setInputStream("");
                    tempClient.setShouldSend(false);
                }
            }

        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error in serverWorker");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

}

Whole of ServerWorkerListener:

```
    public class ServerWorkerListener implements Runnable {

private BufferedReader input;
private Socket clientSocket;

public ServerWorkerListener(Socket clientSocket) {
    this.clientSocket = clientSocket;
    run();
}

@Override
public void run() {
    System.out.println("its running");
    try {

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                clientSocket.getInputStream()));

        while (true) {
            System.out.println("it's looping");
            String inputLine = null;
            if ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, inputLine, "InfoBox: "
                        + "Message from client",
                        JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

            }
        }

    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        System.err.println("Don't know about client");
        System.exit(1);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Couldn't get I/O for the connection to client");
        System.exit(1);

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Is there any blocking code in the constructor of ServerWorkerListener?

Comment: Could you publish the source of whole ServerWorker and ServerWorkerListener classes?

Comment: Updated and thanks for taking a look!

Comment: You *must not* invoke `run()` inside the constructor of `ServerWorkerListener`. The new thread ought to invoke `run()`, otherwise, since it contains an infinite loop, it will never return from the constructor and hence never invoke the `Thread`’s constructor, not to speak of its `start` method.

Comment: Yes! That's the answer. How do I accept it? Thank you so much...

Comment: wait for @Holger to move his comment into an answer, then accept that

Comment: ..which you would have discovered easily if you had used a debugger and so found out that the start method was never executed.

Comment: You're right about the debugger. I need to learn to use it... Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are invoking `run()` inside the constructor of `ServerWorkerListener`, which you *must not* do. The new thread ought to invoke `run()`, otherwise, since it contains an infinite loop, it will never return from the constructor and hence never invoke the `Thread`’s constructor, not to speak of its start method. So removing `run()` the invocation from the constructor should solve the problem.